# How to fetch translation record in django

Tags: django, python-3.x

I am new in django framework.I have 3 tables in mysql database. I want to fetch data from main table with translation table and images table.
My model.py

```
class Country(models.Model):
    #id             = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
    iso_code    = models.CharField(max_length=2, unique=True)
    slug        = models.CharField(max_length=255, unique=True)
    is_featured = models.IntegerField(max_length=1)

    class Meta:
        db_table = 'rh_countries'

class CountryTranslation(models.Model):
    country_id  = models.ForeignKey(Country, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    name        = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    description = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
    locale      = models.CharField(max_length=2)

    class Meta:
        db_table = 'rh_countries_translations'

class CountryImage(models.Model):
    country_id  = models.ForeignKey(Country, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    image       = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    is_main     = models.IntegerField(max_length=1)

    class Meta:
        db_table = 'rh_country_images'
```

Now I want to fetch all country with translation record by locale and associated image.
Please give a solution if anyone know.

Comment: Please rename your foreignkeys to `country`, *not* `country_id`. Django will automatically create an extra `country_id` column with the `id` of the foreign key.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this by using a filtering, and annotate:

```
from django.db.models import F

Country.objects.filter(
    countrytranslation__locale=mylocale
).annotate(
    name=F('countrytranslation__name')
)
```

This will result in a `QuerySet` with all `Country`s (that have a `Translation` for the given `mylocale`). These `Country`s will have an extra attribute `.name` that is the translated name of the `Country`.

So given the translations exist, then for `mylocale='en'`, this will result in a `QuerySet`, with `Country(name='Germany', iso_code='de')`, and for `mylocale='de'`, it will result in `Country(name='Deutschland', iso_code='de')` (here this is a bit an *ad hoc* format, to demonstrate how it works).

> **Note**: `ForeignKey`s typically do *not* end with `_id`. Django will automatically add an `_id` suffix to the database column. The foreign key itself is on the Python/Django level represented as a lazy loaded attribute.

Comment: @raj: you need to import it... `from django.db.models import F`.

Comment: got another error Cannot resolve keyword 'country_translation' into field. Choices are: countryimage, countrytranslation, id, is_featured, iso_code, slug

Comment: @Raj: well if you take a look at the choices, it is rather obvious that the underscore was a mistake :)

Comment: QuerySet.annotate() received non-expression(s): Country object (countrytranslation__name).

Comment: yes got another error -- QuerySet.annotate() received non-expression(s): Country object (countrytranslation__name).

Comment: @Raj: I've tested it locally and it works. Are you sure that the error is (a) on this line, (b) the code is crroect, (c) you provided the exact models?

Comment: this is the same model.py and my views.py is def index(request):
    #return HttpResponse("Hello, world. You're at the polls index.")
    template = loader.get_template('home/index.html')
    context = {
     "countries" : Country.objects.filter(
          countrytranslation__locale='en'
      ).annotate(
          name=Country('countrytranslation__name')
      )
    }
    return render(request, 'home/index.html', context)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/179619/discussion-between-raj-and-willem-van-onsem).

Comment: But you wrote `name=Country(..)`, not `name=F(..)`.